# failed_to_parse_configuration_file on rabbitmq

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

So I just wanted to change default username password from guest to sth else on rabbitmq
but nothing works for me...
this is my rabbitmq.conf

```
[
  {rabbit,
    [
      {default_vhost,       <<"/">>},
      {default_user,        <<"itsme">>},
      {default_pass,        <<"ok">>}
    ]
  }
].
```

and my docker-compose:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    # Also tried env_file and environment variables
    # env_file:
    #     - ./docs/server/stack/dev/configs/rabbitmq/.env
    # environment:
    #   RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: itsme
    #   RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: ok
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - ./configs/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
    networks:
      - rabbitmq_network
```

and error that i get:

```
    BOOT FAILED
    
    ===========
    
    Error during startup: {error,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}
    
    Application rabbitmq_prelaunch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_parse_configuration_file}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

2022-01-03 11:50:58.446386+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> Error parsing configuration:

2022-01-03 11:50:58.464588+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0>   - Syntax error in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf after line 1 column 1, parsing incomplete

2022-01-03 11:50:58.464617+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> Are these files using the Cuttlefish format?
```

i also tried to do it as config file:

```
default_user = itsme
default_pass = ok
stomp.default_user = itsme
stomp.default_pass = ok
mqtt.default_user = itsme
mqtt.default_pass = ok
amqp1_0.default_user = itsme
```

and errors:

```
{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_read_advanced_configuration_file}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

2022-01-03 12:20:01.457976+00:00 [erro] <0.130.0> Failed to load advanced configuration file "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config": 2: syntax error before: default_pass
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was that the file was named with the ".config" suffix.
".config" is for the advanced configuration.

Modifying it to ".conf" resolved the issue for me.

Reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-file